# BigQuery How to get the sum of values in a JSON struct?

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have the below query

```
SELECT 
    JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.Weights') as weight 
from 
(select '{"Weights":{"blue":1.0,"purple":0.0,"yellow":1.0,"green":1.0}}' as json)
```

which returns :

> {"blue":1.0,"purple":0.0,"yellow":1.0,"green":1.0}

I would like to see if there is a way to **sum up** all the values of the colors. Meaning to return:

> 3.0

I have been trying using split and unnest functions without any success, any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example using `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL`:

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT '{"Weights":{"blue":1.0,"purple":0.0,"yellow":1.0,"green":1.0}}' AS json
)
SELECT
  (
    SELECT SUM(CAST(val AS FLOAT64))
    FROM UNNEST(
      REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(
        JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.Weights'),
        r':([^,}]+)')
    ) AS val
  )
FROM T;
```

Comment: Work perfect. Thanks very much !

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of exploring other options -

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

First example is to extract key:value pair for each row

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.yourTbale` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, '{"Weights":{"blue":1.0,"purple":0.0,"yellow":1.0,"green":1.0}}' AS json 
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, '{"Weights":{"blue":1.0,"red":2.0,"yellow":1.0,"orange":3.0}}'
)
SELECT id,
  REPLACE(SPLIT(pair, ':')[OFFSET (0)], '"', '') color, 
  SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(pair, ':')[OFFSET (1)] AS FLOAT64) value
FROM `project.dataset.yourTbale`, 
UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.Weights'), r'{|}', ''))) pair
```

this gives you below result

```
id  color   value    
1   blue    1.0  
1   purple  0.0  
1   yellow  1.0  
1   green   1.0  
2   blue    1.0  
2   red     2.0  
2   yellow  1.0  
2   orange  3.0
```

so now it is simple to extend above to your original question of `if there is a way to sum up all the values of the colors` and even extend it more with potentially filtering on specific color(s) - see example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.yourTbale` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, '{"Weights":{"blue":1.0,"purple":0.0,"yellow":1.0,"green":1.0}}' AS json 
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, '{"Weights":{"blue":1.0,"red":2.0,"yellow":1.0,"orange":3.0}}'
)
SELECT id,
  SUM(SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(pair, ':')[OFFSET (1)] AS FLOAT64)) AS total
FROM `project.dataset.yourTbale`, 
UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.Weights'), r'{|}', ''))) pair
WHERE REPLACE(SPLIT(pair, ':')[OFFSET (0)], '"', '') != 'blue'
GROUP BY id
```

with result as below (which excludes color=blue from calc)

```
id  total    
1   2.0  
2   6.0
```

Comment: This one also works very nicely, thanks for your answer, Mikhail!